# Зачем нужен __iter__, когда есть __next__?

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, итераторы, дизайн-языка

Я учу python и у меня возник вопрос по итераторам.
Чтобы можно было итерироваться по объекту, у него должен быть метод `__iter__`, который вернет объект-итератор.
У объекта-итератора должен быть метод `__next__`, который будет возвращать следующий элемент из объекта, по которому итерируемся, либо кидать ошибку `StopIteration`.
Я встречал только такой код, в котором `__iter__` возвращает `self`.
Например

```py
class RandomIterator:
    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __init__(self, k):
        self.k = k
        self.i = 0

    def __next__(self):
        if self.i < self.k:
            self.i += 1
            return random()
        else:
            raise StopIteration
```

Вот у меня и возник вопрос, какой смысл от метода `__iter__`?

Comment: В данном случае объект сам по себе и является итератором, но в общем случае объект и итератор не обязаны быть одним и тем же объектом. Например, у списка `list` итератором является отдельный объект `list_iterator`, а не сам список

Comment: Например, для ситуации, когда нужно создать несколько независимых итераторов по одному контейнеру.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`__iter__()` в Python](https://pythonru.com/uroki/iteratory-python-uroki-po-python-dlja-nachinajushhih)

> Как вы узнали из урока «Классы и объекты Python», у всех классов есть функция под названием `__init__()`, которая позволяет вам делать инициализацию при создании объекта.
>
> Метод `__iter__()` действует аналогично, вы можете выполнять операции (инициализацию и т. Д.), Но всегда должны возвращать сам объект итератора.

[немного хабра](https://habr.com/ru/post/186608/)

> Теперь, когда речь зашла о создании собственных последовательностей в Питоне, пришло время поговорить о протоколах. Протоколы немного похожи на интерфейсы в других языках тем, что они предоставляют набор методов, которые вы должны реализовать. Однако, в Питоне протоколы абсолютно ни к чему не обязывают и не требуют обязательно реализовать какое-либо объявление. Наверное, они больше похожи на руководящие указания.
>
> Почему мы заговорили о протоколах? Потому, что реализация произвольных контейнерных типов в Питоне влечёт за собой использование некоторых из них. Во-первых, протокол для определения неизменяемых контейнеров: чтобы создать неизменяемый контейнер, вы должны только определить `__len__` и `__getitem__` (продробнее о них дальше). Протокол изменяемого контейнера требует того же, что и неизменяемого контейнера, плюс `__setitem__` и `__delitem__`. И, наконец, если вы хотите, чтобы ваши объекты можно было перебирать итерацией, вы должны определить `__iter__`, который возвращает итератор. Этот итератор должен соответствовать протоколу итератора, который требует методов `__iter__`(возвращает самого себя) и next.
>
> `__iter__(self)`
>   Должен вернуть итератор для контейнера. Итераторы возвращаются в множестве ситуаций, главным образом для встроенной функции `iter()` и в случае перебора элементов контейнера выражением `for x in container:`. Итераторы сами по себе объекты и они тоже должны определять метод `__iter__`, который возвращает `self`.

---

**UPDATE** (вернул пример с кодом, ибо попросили в комментах): Вот в примере по [1-й](https://habr.com/ru/post/186608/) ссылке есть один из вариантов зачем. Когда вам нужно считать кол-во элеметов обработанных или иные связанные операции. Это полезно для уменьшения кол-во дублирования кода (см. принципы языка Python)iter() в Python

```
class MyNumbers:
    def __iter__(self):
        self.a = 1
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        x = self.a
        self.a += 1
        return x
```

А вот ниже мой пример использования `__iter__`

```
class Fibbonachi:

    def __iter__(self):
        self.cur_val = 0
        self.next_val = 1
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        tmp = self.next_val
        self.next_val += self.cur_val
        self.cur_val = tmp
        return tmp


for i in Fibbonachi():
    print(i)
    if i > 100: break

# Результат: 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144 в колонку
```

Comment: Пример с кодом был нагляднее.

Answer (score 3):

Вообще, такой подход (с использованием только `__iter__`) на мой взгляд намного проще, поэтому вопрос скорее должен был бы звучать наоборот, зачем нужен `__next__` :)

```
class RandomIterator:
    def __iter__(self):
        while self.i < self.k:
            self.i += 1
            yield random()

    def __init__(self, k):
        self.k = k
        self.i = 0
```

Answer (score -1):

> > Вот у меня и возник вопрос, какой смысл от метода **iter**?

`__iter__` это просто хороший дизайн, которые отделяет итератор от самого объекта или контейера по которому итерируетесь, можно обойтись без него для вашего примера.

За любыми вопросами обращайтесь к официальной литературе и первоисточникам:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#iterators

Comment: Постарайтесь давать более развернутые овтеты. В данном варианте он не информативен. Если на этом ресурсе ограничиваться ссылками на официальную документацию в ответах, то он не нужен.

Comment: Немного подправил.

Comment: Это не правда. Ресур нужен не смотря на официальную документацию. Читать спецификации долго и нужны ориентиры по ним. Так что я не рекомендую вам искать какие-то противоречия. С опытом чтения большого кол-ва документов и спецификацией вам это откроется через некоторое время. Т.е. SO как феномен дополняет документацию, или создаёт базу знаний по большим проектам.